# Python PPTX workaround to add Transitions to slides

Tags: python, powerpoint, python-pptx

I successfully automated the creation of pptx presentations using `python-pptx`, customising background, inserting text, images, etc.

How can I add custom **Transitions** to my slides? (E.g. "Transitions" > "Fade" from PowerPoint). As I could not find a function, my idea is to use workaround functions (going deep into xml): where do I start?

python 3.10.4,
PowerPoint v16.54,
MacOS Big Sur 11.6

[image]

Comment: I think you need first to establish whether a transition is a slide-level thing or a presentation-level thing. That would guide you as to which XML file to examine.

Comment: From the documentation below (pag.153) it seems a slide-level thing:
name="transition" type="CT_SlideTransition"
But how do I manipulate that?

https://readthedocs.org/projects/python-pptx/downloads/pdf/latest/

Comment: I'm going to play with this - for my md2pptx project. It is about finding the slide's XML element , I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, on playing with this, the following worked for me:

```
    xml = '''
      <mc:AlternateContent xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006">
    <mc:Choice xmlns:p14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/powerpoint/2010/main" Requires="p14">
      <p:transition xmlns:p="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/presentationml/2006/main" spd="slow" p14:dur="3400">
        <p14:ripple />
      </p:transition>
    </mc:Choice>
    <mc:Fallback>
      <p:transition xmlns:p="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/presentationml/2006/main" spd="slow">
        <p:fade />
      </p:transition>
    </mc:Fallback>
  </mc:AlternateContent>
   '''
    xmlFragment = parse_xml(xml)
    slide.element.insert(-1, xmlFragment)
```

Where `slide` is the slide object in python-pptx.

You probably need the following import:

```
from pptx.oxml import parse_xml
```

Where I have `ripple` I first tested with `reveal` - and that worked as well. I'm sure there are other transitions. Before I attempt to add them to [md2pptx](https://github.com/MartinPacker/md2pptx) I will want to find some more and figure out what kind of UI I want to surface them with.

Hope this helps.

(Edited for grammar.)

Comment: It turns out that different slide transition effects require different namespaces. Also that some require additional attributes on the `<transition>` element. I haven't caught them all in md2pptx but I will be adding a few more very soon (as I got them working while on a business trip). So the advice remains to examine the slide's XML when you create the transition by hand. In all cases so far the code I posted is a good starting point.